# how to minimize the space between my branding components

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a top level nav bar, But currently the login username, the date & time and the search are having many space between them as follow:-

[image]

but is there a way to minimize the space between the components same as shown below:-
[image]

my current html for  the top navigation is :-

```
<section id="login" class="navbar-search pull-right">
<span class="username" style=" display:block;"><i class="icon-user"></i><strong> @User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1)</strong></span>
<div style="text-align:right">
<p id="currentdate"></p>
<p id="currenttime" ></p>   
    </div>
<form class="customSearch" method="GET" action="@Url.Action("Search", "Home")">
<input  class="searchInput" placeholder="Search" name="searchTerm2" data-autocomplete-source= "@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Home")" type="text"  />
</form>
                    </section>
```

Comment: Can you show your CSS? You probably need to do something with margin / padding / line-height.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you use Chrome browser to inspect the elements and see where goes wrong in your CSS, easy and handy, I do it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

use line-height, margin or padding property in css.